# "as a/my birthday gift' or "for a/my birthday gift"

Tags: word-choice

(1) I received this watch **as a** birthday gift.

(2) I received this watch **as my** birthday gift.

(3) I received this watch **for a** birthday gift.

(4) I received this watch **for my** birthday gift.

Which sentence(s) is/are correct?

Answer (score 3):

1 and 2 are alright.
2 suggests that the watch was your *only* birthday gift.

3 and 4 aren't the usual way of putting it, but this would be idiomatic:

> I received this watch for my birthday.

Comment: I would expect 'my birthday gift' to be followed by 'from my parents' (or husband, sister etc.) - someone you would routinely expect a special gift from.